# how to get jre 9 to work in appx package

Tags: java, windows, appx, makeappx

I have a java app that I wrote in the windows store.
Up until now the appx package has just contained the app and a line in the description says "Java needed for this app to work".

With the oncoming windows 10S, the windows store now wants the jre bundled with the app in the appx package.

With the help of launch4j to make my java program executable and makeappx I can make the necessary package if I make it with JRE 8.The problem is that it makes for a very large install.

I want to use JRE 9 as I can make the JRE half the size smaller using JLink.

The problem is when I pack JRE9 into the appx package with my app it will not work. But it works fine outside of the appx package.